# Windows - make hosts file affect ICS

Tags: windows, wireless-networking, hosts-file, ad-hoc-network, ics

I am running an Ad Hoc Wi-Fi network (Hosted network using Microsoft Virtual WiFi Miniport Adapter) on my PC. I used ICS (Internet Connection Sharing) to link my existing Wi-Fi connection through to the Ad Hoc network, so people on the Ad Hoc network can access the internet through my connection.

What I am trying to do is add some custom hosts, so that people on the Ad Hoc network can for example go to `foobar.com` and be directed to my PC's server. So, I added the following lines to my hosts file in `%windir%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts':

```
192.168.137.1 foobar.com
192.168.137.1 www.foobar.com
```

Where `192.168.137.1` is my PC's IP on the Ad Hoc network. While this change affected my machine, it had no effect for any other device on the network.

How can I make my hosts file affect devices on my Ad Hoc network?

Answer (score 1):

You can't. The Hosts file is effective only for the local DNS client. If you need to have other clients resolve the entries in your Hosts file you'll need to set up an internal DNS server and configure your clients to use it for DNS.